# couchbase php delete and get

Tags: php, couchbase

This is my COUNT query

```
$query = CouchbaseN1qlQuery::fromString("SELECT count(*) as cont FROM testdb");
```

And this is my DELETE query

```
$bucket->remove("abc123");
```

If I run these in this sequence

```
count query ->  10 docs
delete query -> ok
count query ->  10 docs
```

why my count is always 10 documents?
How can I do sync operation or does exist a better way?
I'm sure that document with id "abc123" exists because before I run a query to check if exists.

**EDIT**

The solution for me is this

```
$query->consistency(\Couchbase\N1qlQuery::REQUEST_PLUS);
```

more info https://github.com/couchbaselabs/devguide-examples/blob/master/php/query-consistency.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible behaviour with default query consistency level. You can read more about them in API documentation: http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-php-client-2.4.1/classes/Couchbase.N1qlQuery.html#method_consistency

Also in N1QL section of the server reference: https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/architecture/querying-data-with-n1ql.html

Also repository with developer guides contains an example of queries with different consistency levels: https://github.com/couchbaselabs/devguide-examples/blob/master/php/query-consistency.php

Comment: Well done @avsej, your last link is the solution for my problem. I have added to my code this $query->consistency(\Couchbase\N1qlQuery::REQUEST_PLUS);